# LeafLet to show between places

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet map in my project.

```
Suppose I have two markers in my map say A and B 
then how can i show direction from A to B place using leaflet.
```

Any Example related to this??
Or any other open source Map i can use??

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think Leaflet can do this. You can use [**MapQuest**](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/sdk) if you want to do some [**routing**](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/open-sdk/javascript/v7.2/routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Leaflet Routing Machine](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) plug-in as shown in this [link](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/). You just need to include the appropriate css and js files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
<script src="leaflet-routing-machine.min.js"></script>
```

and do something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94), //first marker position
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949) //second marker position
    ]
}).addTo(map);
```